# Recursion Quiz - Couldn't Solve

Tags: python, recursion

Today my CPSC professor assigned a quiz in python, the topic was recursion.

The whole class got stuck on question number two, which is below. Nobody was able to even come close to a solution.

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return A
    X = sub_set(A[1:])
    result = []
    for L in X:
        result += _____
    return _____
```

Example code:

```
print(sub_set([1, 2]))    # [[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
print(sub_set([1, 2, 3])) # [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

You are only allowed to modify the underscores, such as my example below may demonstrate.

My solution was so far from close, it really shouldn't even be considered:

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return A
    X = sub_set(A[1:])
    result = []
    for L in X:
        result += _____
    return result + [A[:1]] + [A] + [A[::2]]

#sub_set([1, 2, 3]) -> [[3], [3], [3], [2], [2, 3], [2], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

Does anyone know how this could be solved? It seems like quite a challenging problem when we have only 15 minutes to solve it.

Just for reference, he said he would drop the question considering nobody in the class - advanced comp sci class of about 10 carefully selected students - could solve it.

Comment: This seems to be a problem to generate all permutations of length 1..n of a list — but looking at [other solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python), none of them seem to be in the form. The question is probably wrong.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: The example code makes it quite clear that `sub_set` is supposed to return a list of all "subsets" of the given list, not permutations.  If it were permutations, `[2,1,3]` and `[3,2,1]` (among others) would be in the output from `sub_set([1,2,3])` in addition to `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there's a bug in the question. The base case for the recursion is wrong.

The set of all subsets of an empty set is not the empty set, but rather, the set containing the empty set.

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return A
```

should be

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return [A]
```

**Added:** With that patch, here's a solution:

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return [A]
    X = sub_set(A[1:])
    result = []
    for L in X:
        result += [L, A[0:1] + L]
    return result
```

Comment: After banging my head against it for 20-odd minutes, I'm convinced you're right.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if maybe this was a trick question, and the point was for the students to figure out that the base case is wrong (which should be doable in 15 minutes)… Either way, noa gets the extra credit for the class; the question is whether the professor gets an F or not. :)

Comment: Haha, sounds about right. 15 minutes to realize the base case is wrong, and another 20 to learn what `+` does to a Python list.

Comment: @noa: But `+` doesn't do anything to a list, unless the other operand has an `__radd__(self, other)` method that mutates `other`. :) (I know what you mean, just being silly.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I brought this up with him and this was indeed the case. It was just a bug in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this is solvable without some major hackery, because the base case is wrong. For `[]`, there should be one subset: `[]` itself. But `return A` returns *no* subsets.

So, instead of just doing `A[:1] + L`, you need to do `[A[:1] + L]`. And, instead of `A[:1] + X + result`, you have to do `[A[:1]] + X + result`. So:

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return A
    X = sub_set(A[1:])
    result = []
    for L in X:
        result += [A[:1] + L]
    return [A[:1]] + X + result
```

This still leaves the empty list out of the subsets for anything. And the only way to fix that is something stupid like this:

```
    return ([] if [] in X + result else [[]]) + [A[:1]] + X + result
```

This will at least return the right values… but in the wrong order, and with duplicates of all one-element subsets. You can extend the hackiness further if you want; I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return A
    X = sub_set(A[1:])
    result = []
    for L in X:
        result += [L, [A[0]]+L]
    return [[A[0]]] + result

print sub_set([1, 2])
>> [[1], [2], [1, 2]]
print sub_set([1, 2, 3])
>> [[1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Doesn't include `[]`, and isn't in the order specified.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, didn't notice that the `[]` was supposed to be in there.  Not sure if the order is supposed to matter, though.

Comment: Fixed the order, but not sure how to get the empty set in there.

Comment: If you ignore the bug in the original question, you're correct. +1.

Comment: After the last edit, this is exactly the same as my comment on Scott Hunter's answer, and therefore is wrong for the same reasons my comment was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return A
    X = sub_set(A[1:])
    result = []
    for L in X:
        result += [L, A[0:1] + L]
    return result if X != [] else [[], A[0:1]]
```

This is essentially the same as [noa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893113/noa) answer, minus the change to the part of the code you're not supposed to edit.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Rather than just posting the code, it would be more helpful for the OP if an explanation is added to it :)

Answer (score 0):

`X` is the set of all subsets that DON'T include `A[0]`.  This means that they are also in `subset(A)`.  What's missing is all the subsets that DO contain `A[0]`, which you can get by adding `A[0]` to each of the elements in `X`.

So your first blank would be `A[0] + L`

And your second would be `result + X`

Comment: That returns `[]` for any input. Try it.

Comment: If you changed it to `[[A[0]] + L]`, that would be closer… but then you'd need to also add `[[A[0]]]` to the second blank. And you still wouldn't get the empty list in your results.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution you are looking for, but here's a working solution using yield :)

```
def powerset(A):
    if A:
        for L in powerset(A[1:]):
            yield L
            yield A[:1] + L
    else:
        yield []
```

Comment: If you're going to answer a different question, why not just `return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))`?

Comment: I just realized that what I typed is character-for-character identical to `powerset` in the `itertools` [recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). So, I guess I'm less clever than I thought, but it's even more the "obvious way to do it" than I thought. :)

Comment: @abarnert: simply because I find this version slightly easier to read :) But nothing is stopping you from posting that as an answer ;)

Comment: Well, it's even easier to read `return more_itertools.powerset(A)`. :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible solution. it returns the right values, but not necessarily in the same order:

```
def sub_set(A):
    if A == []: return A
    X = sub_set(A[1:])
    result = []
    for L in X:
        result += [ A[:1] +L ]
    return [[]] + X[1:] + (result or [A[:1]])
```

Effectively what this is doing, is for each layer, we split the original list into two parts: the initial item, and the rest of the list. We get all subsets of the rest of the list, append the first item to each piece, prepend a [], and return it.

Example flow:

```
[1,2,3] -> A0 = [1], A1X =[2,3] ->
    [2,3] -> A0 = [2], A1X = [3] ->
        [3] -> A0 = [3], A1X = [] ->
            [] -> return []
        [3] * [] = []. return [ [], [3] ]
    [2] * [[], [3]] = [[2], [2,3]]. return [ [] + [[3]] + [[2], [2,3]] ]
[1] * [ [], [3], [2], [2,3] ] = [[1], [1,3], [1,2], [1, 2, 3] ]
             return [ [] + [[], [3], [2], [2,3]] + [[1], [1,3], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

General flow is [] + A0*[subset] + [subset]. Issues to watch are that subset itself always starts with [] - so you'll get it twice if you don't remove it, and to make sure you don't duplicate A0 when it's already there (as [A0] + [] == [A0], and you always have [A0] in the list), but on the very first iteration (after returning []) you have to specially include it.